# How do I make an HTTP request in Ruby on Rails to get data from Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I make an HTTP request in ruby on rails to get data from facebook. I am unsure of where to start to get data from the facebook API in json format.

I hope this question even makes sense.

Comment: Do you want to make requests from the server side or the JavaScript?

Comment: I guess what I am basically asking is how do I make http requests in general. I don't quite understand it at all, and I know that it is essential to learn about them to pretty much interact with data from other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be dealing with FB in Rails you will want to take a look at [mogli](https://github.com/mmangino/mogli) and [facebooker2](https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2). If you can provide some more detail, people will be able to help you better but at least that's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need JSON data, use rest-client.

https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client

I recommend use this instead of original rest-client gem, since original one doesn't force SSL certificate verification.

https://github.com/nov/restclient_with_cert